# How to immediately delete email from server after archiving it in thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird

In my current setup, when thunderbird archives an e-mail it is only marked for deletion, not delete immediately from the server. How do I set it up to actually delete the mail from the server ?

Comment: Is it POP3 or IMAP?

Comment: I have to say in 11 characters or more that it is IMAP.

Answer (score 0):

For IMAP, from within Thunderbird:

1. `Edit` -> `Settings`
2. In the `General` tab, go right to the bottom and click on the `Config Editor` button.
3. Search for `mail.imap.expunge_after_delete` in the search bar.
4. Change the default `false` value to `true` by hitting the Toggle button.
5. Quite and restart Thunderbird.

Most of this was from [How to Get Mozilla Thunderbird to Delete Messages on the Mail Server When Using IMAP](https://www.hostm.com/tutorials/email/thunderbird-imap-delete).  I had to make some changes, however.  (e.g. it didn't mention that a restart was necessary.)

Answer (score 0):

#gmail & archive in thunderbird

DELETE->OK: when you delete a message in thunderbird it is deleted on server
ARCHIVE->KO: when you "archive" a message in thunderbird it is not deleted on server.

thunderbird should be fixed!!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).